# Is E&R the place to ask about questions of programming, but related to microcontrollers?

Tags: discussion

Hi,

I wanted to ask some programming related question on E&R but for a microcontroller. I decided to postpone it until I got the go-ahead.

"What is the ISR for the comparator change interrupt on a dsPIC33F?"

Comment: It would really be great if this site could have a relaxed attitude towards embedded systems programming questions. Just look at [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98858/algorithm-for-finding-next-data-in-eeprom), someone asked about an algorithm for searching through EEPROM and it got closed as off-topic. Seriously, where should he ask then??? The people on SO don't even know what EEPROM means, let alone what issues you may encounter when designing algorithms for accessing them.

Answer (score 9):

Absolutely!  (In my humble opinion)

I assume that anything related to peripherals or interrupts is a better fit for here than SO.

Many questions about general programming on a microcontroller which are space/time constrained are also a better fit here.  Most SO users assume a 2GHz machine with 4GB of RAM, infinite disk space, a complete set of drivers, and an OS.  If that's not the case for your project, then it's likely a better fit here.

Of course, for some of the programming problems you'll encounter, the platform doesn't matter. If you could run into the same problem on a PC, then it's probably better over at SO.

In the end, I think it comes down to a question of utility: Where are you more likely to get the answer you want?  On SO, 80% of the users don't know what 'ISR' stands for, 95%% of them don't know what a comparator is, and 99% of them don't know what a dsPIC33F is. On E&R, I'd guess that 99% of the users know what 'ISR' stands for, 95% know what a comparator is, and 80% know what a dsPIC33F is.  Many E&R users probably have the datasheet on their hard drive.

[Note: All statistics made up on the spot.]

Also, I'll answer your question here for now, drop me a comment when you decide to post it to SO or E&R and I'll move it over there.  [Whole bunch of Output Capture related stuff removed  :P  ].

Comment: Thanks! But that's for output capture. I'm going to post a question on E&R SE in a few mins.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/what-is-the-isr-for-the-comparator-change-interrupt-on-a-dspic33f

Comment: Whoops!  "Answer" removed.

Comment: Reemrevnivek is spot on, as expected. The SO site is really for programming on an OS.